# jQuery - Randomize boxes and animate them on window load

Tags: jquery, random, jquery-animate

On the picture bellow is what I'm trying to build:
[image: random boxes]

Idea is that all the boxes are hidden until whole page loads. Then they should have set random positions around browser view port and then they (boxes) needs to be animated to move to their proper positions.

Boxes have absolute positions in CSS, and my idea is when windows loads to put initial position in variable, then randomize position of the box, and then finally move it to the starting position. Hope I'm clear :)

**Here is my current setup: http://jsfiddle.net/HgMB4/**

You will notice that I'm missing code on window load, because I'm not sure how to animate boxes to their initial position.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //Huh! What to write here to animate boxes to their initial positions set by CSS?
});
```

Comment: Have a look at jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), jQuery UI's [toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) or [CSS3 transformations](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-animations/) if that is applicable to you. Regardless, what you are looking for you have a final target location for each box you specify in a CSS for example and use either one of the above to move each box to their final destination using animation or transformations. This should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var h = $(window).height();
      var w = $(window).width();            
      $('#intro .box').each(function(){
            var originalOffset = $(this).position(),
            $this = $(this),
            tLeft = w-Math.floor(Math.random()*900),
            tTop  = h-Math.floor(Math.random()*900);

           $(this).animate({"left": tLeft , "top": tTop},5000,function(){
                           $this.animate({
                               "left": originalOffset.left, 
                               "top": originalOffset.top
                           },5000);

                        });        
    });
});
​
```

This will animate the boxes to random position and then will move them back to their original position.

Here is the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/HgMB4/18

If you want to animate boxes only when they move to initial position then try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();            
    $('#intro .box').each(function(){
        var originalOffset = $(this).position(),
            $this = $(this),
           tLeft = w-Math.floor(Math.random()*900),
           tTop  = h-Math.floor(Math.random()*900);

        $(this).css({
            "left": tLeft,
            "top": tTop
        });

        $this.animate({ "left": originalOffset.left, 
                         "top": originalOffset.top
                     },5000);

    });
});
​
​
```

Here is the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/HgMB4/22

Answer (score 1):

> **Requirements**
>
> - boxes are hidden until whole page loads
> - boxes are set to random positions around browser view port
> - boxes need to animate to their proper positions

You can store the original position and after your random placement start animating them to go back to their starting position. I also cached any DOM reference which were repeated to speed up the code execution (most likely not noticeably but it's good practice)

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/az2SL/) - Boxes placed at random and then animated back to their proper positions.

I have separated the 2 actions, placing the boxes at random locations using your original code but now also storing the original position in associated data using [**jQuery's Data**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) which is then used to animate them back to their proper positions.

You can now randomise and re-set the boxes on demand by calling either method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();
    var $allBoxes = $('#intro .box');

    placeBoxesRandomly($allBoxes, h, w);
    
    placeBoxesToDataStorePositions($allBoxes);
});​
```

`placeBoxesRandomly` still does what it did before except it now also associates the original starting position data with the elements:

```
function placeBoxesRandomly($boxes, h, w) {
    $boxes.each(function() {
        var $box = $(this);
        var position = $box.position();

        tLeft = w - Math.floor(Math.random() * 900), tTop = h - Math.floor(Math.random() * 900);
        $box.css({
            "left": tLeft,
            "top": tTop
        });
        $box.data("start-position-left", position.left);
        $box.data("start-position-top", position.top);
    });
}
```

`placeBoxesToDataStorePositions` places the boxes to the positions stored in the associated data.

```
function placeBoxesToDataStorePositions($boxes) {
    $boxes.each(function() {
        var $box = $(this);
        $box.animate({
            "left": $box.data("start-position-left"),
            "top": $box.data("start-position-top")
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [jQuery Isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html). This [Stack-exchange page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) his this implented with a variation of it