# Jquery animation to be start when scroll to that portion of page

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I want one page scroll type animation on my webpage so i follow [this tutorial](http://ihatetomatoes.net/one-page-scroll-with-animations/) and successfully implemented this.

now suppose I have five scroll portion in my webpage that is I can scroll maximum five time or there are five different section in the page.

I want to implement this
[box animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003021/jquery-randomize-boxes-and-animate-them-on-window-load) at one of the section in the page. according to this animation six boxes are at random position and then they embed to a div. I again successfully implement this.

But there is a problem.

I want the box animation to be started when i scroll to that section of my page, that means if the box animation is at 5th section of the page and when i move to 5th section that animation starts.

How can I implement this?

code to respective animation is already linked above

**jquery code for box-animation**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var h = $(window).height();
var w = $(window).width();            
$('#intro .box').each(function(){
    var originalOffset = $(this).position(),
        $this = $(this),
       tLeft = w-Math.floor(Math.random()*900),
       tTop  = h-Math.floor(Math.random()*900);

    $(this).css({
        "left": tLeft,
        "top": tTop
    });

    $this.animate({ "left": originalOffset.left, 
                     "top": originalOffset.top
                 },5000);

    });
});
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling